# Getting current date and time in C++

Tags: c++, project, turbo-c++

I am doing a school project which basically records the in and out time of an employee(of an particular company).The employee while checking in or out should enter a unique key generated specially for him so that no one else can check in and out for him.Then referring to the employees position( A worker or a manager or something like that) his total working time each day , for a week and a month is calculated. The company starts at 8 am and ends at 5 pm for 1st shift and for second shift from 3.30 pm to 2.30 am.Plus Saturday and Sunday off.

Then after a month the program refers to the working time date stored in a file and calculates his pay(For workers its per hour salary and for managers it aint). If an employee is consistently late the details are forwarded to the HR account( so that necessary steps are taken).This will help the company log the details of their employees duty time plus give enough detail to take action if someones always late.

I'm doing this as a school project and it needn't be of enterprise class and all.. But i want the coding to perform as it should.Also i'm forced to use the old Turbo C++.

Now i'm struck in the place where the time of the employees in and out time is logged.

This coding does the work

```
void main( )
{
clrscr();
char dateStr [9],timeStr [9];
_strdate( dateStr);
cout<<" The current date is "<<dateStr<<'\n';
_strtime( timeStr );
cout<<" The current time is "<<timeStr<<'\n';
getch();
}
```

I saw it somewhere on the web but can someone help me understand how it works.

I also saw another coding

```
typedef struct _SYSTEMTIME {
WORD wYear;
WORD wMonth;
WORD wDayOfWeek;
WORD wDay;
WORD wHour;
WORD wMinute;
WORD wSecond;
WORD wMilliseconds;
} SYSTEMTIME;

#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
SYSTEMTIME st;
GetSystemTime(&st);
printf("Year:%dnMonth:%dnDate:%dnHour:%dnMin:%dnSecond:% dn" 
st.wYear,st.wMonth,st.wDay,st.wHour,st.wMinute,st.wSecond);                                                                                                        
}
```

I think the second one is better as it not only gives me date but also gives me the day so i can check easily for the weekends.

So help me understand how these time functions work. Also if you have any suggestions for my project they are welcome.

Comment: " i'm forced to use the old Turbo C++" why?

Comment: These are windows specific functions and you are using an obsolete non-standard compliant compiler. Better switch to [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) with a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) compiler and use [`<chrono>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/)

Comment: re `void main`, please do not write that in example code. it is invalid code, and will misled learners reading SO.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Thats what my school has and thats what we are told to work with.

Comment: Maybe you have [time(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html) & [localtime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/localtime.3.html)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Guys please understand i cant change to anything other than that old Turbo C++. That's what everyone in school is forced to work with. Please understand, i cant change the education system here in India!

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Sorry cant understand are you saying i left the header files are what are you trying to say? With header files this code does work in Turbo C++.

Comment: @Approachable You can't, agreed! I'm from India too, but you can always use the right compiler, learn things the right way and adapt it to what the school asks. It's like learning to drive properly showing the right signs in a city and then driving in a village where no one bothers will still work.

Comment: Consider "wrapping" these Turbo C++ isms in an abstraction layer, so that your code would compile on something other that Turbo C++.

Comment: @legends2k Thanks man for understanding my situation. Yes i can learn all them but currently i'm stuck between practicals + board preparation all of those stuff i don't think this is the right time to work on a project(which carries 3 marks out of 500) and spend my whole time in it.

Comment: @ChuckCottrill CUrrently if my code compiles properly in Turbo C++ its more than enough. Thanks for your help though! Would consider what you told in the future but as of now its out of scope.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks those articles seem to help me going through them now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide the format you want to store these clock "events", both for in-memory storage and manipulation and the persistent (on-disk) storage format. When you use different formats for in-memory and on-disk (or in-database) storage, you would use methods to "marshall" or "serialize"/"de-serialize" the data (look up and read about these terms). You also want to decide whether these datetime "events" will be stored or displayed in UTC (Zulu-time, GMT), or local time.  You may find that storing these 'timestamps' in UTC is the best, and then you need functions/methods/routines to convert human-readable, displayable values to/from local time to UTC time.

Consider defining a "class" that has the above methods.  Your class should have a method to record the current time, convert to human readable, and serialize/de-serialize the data.

Though printf works in C++, you might want to use the stream operators you have used in your first example, as they are more in the spirit of C++.  Consider defining a parse method to de-serialize the data, and a to_string method (ruby uses to_s) to serialize (though reading up on stream operator overloading, and overloading the '<<' operator is more the C++ way).

Comment: Looked up for serialize and deserialize thanks god i do know how to store the data in a basic file and then read from it so that shouldn't be a problem. I think storing in UTC or Local time shouldn't be much of a difference as my local time is UTC + 5.30 so thats easy. Well i'll store it in a human readable form itself i.e store the string data directly i needn't change it into binary or something like that its not an essential thing considering its a small program and performance isn't the most important thing.  Oh yeah first one copy edit try paste second one copy paste thats the difference.

Answer (score 0):

The first uses C library functions (though Microsoft extensions to the standard libc). The second uses the winapi function [GetSytemTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Both will give the system time.

The first thing I'd look at is what the rest of your code uses. You should distinguish between what is winapi code, C code and C++ code, currently your question uses a mixture of all three.

The C++ method is preferred (if you are intending to write in C++) which would be to use the newer  library. The C method is as per your first example, though without mixing libc functions with stream operators (a c++ feature). The winapi method is as per your second example (I'll forgive the use of `printf` as `FormatMessage` is a pain).

Comment: This is my current code. Not even 20% of work completed but still this is how far i've got. http://paste.ofcode.org/zUWp2FXkywF44NAsXQ8JvD